# Complicated System of Second Order Differential Equations - Analytic Solution

Tags: python, julia, analytics, differential-equations

I would like to use Julia to find an analytic solution to a very complicated system of second order differential equations. My equations are the following:

```
phi''[t] =
       -(3 (a[t]^2 a'[t] phi'[t] + epsilon a[t]^2 a'[t] phi'[t] + 
       epsilon a[t]^2 Abs[alpha]^2 a'[t] phi'[t] + 
       epsilon Abs[alpha]^2 b[t]^2 b'[t] phi'[t]))/(a[t]^3 + epsilon a[t]^3 + 
       epsilon a[t]^3 Abs[alpha]^2 + epsilon Abs[alpha]^2 b[t]^3)

chi''[t] = 
       -(3 (epsilon a[t]^2 Abs[beta]^2 a'[t] chi'[t] + 
       b[t]^2 b'[t] chi'[t] + epsilon b[t]^2 b'[t] chi'[t] + 
       epsilon Abs[beta]^2 b[t]^2 b'[t] chi'[t]))/(epsilon a[t]^3 Abs[beta]^2 + 
       b[t]^3 + epsilon b[t]^3 + epsilon Abs[beta]^2 b[t]^3)

a''[t] =
       1/(4 a[t]) (-2a'[t]^2 + epsilon a[t]^2 Abs[beta]^2 chi'[t]^2 + 
       a[t]^2 phi'[t]^2 + epsilon a[t]^2 phi'[t]^2 + 
       epsilon a[t]^2 Abs[alpha]^2 phi'[t]^2)

b''[t] =
       1/(4 b[t]) (-2 b'[t]^2 + b[t]^2 chi'[t]^2 + 
       epsilon b[t]^2 chi'[t]^2 + epsilon Abs[beta]^2 b[t]^2 chi'[t]^2 + 
       epsilon Abs[alpha]^2 b[t]^2 phi'[t]^2)
```

where epsilon, alpha, and beta are all constants. Is this possible using Julia? I tried to do this in Mathematica but found that Mathematica was unable to give me an analytic solution. Thank you!

Comment: Why do you expect that an analytical solution exists? Do you mean that in the symbolic sense or as power series? What is the connection to programming? Why do you think Julia-lang would give different/better results than, say, Mathematica?

Comment: Hi Lutz, thank you for your comment! I do expect a symbolic analytic solution to this system of equations will exists as it is well defined and has three free parameters. I am hopeful that Julia could give me better results than Mathematica as it is more powerful when it comes to solving differential equations but I am unfamiliar with how to use it.

Comment: There are many nice and much simpler DE that do not possess a symbolic solution. I'd expect Mathematica to be better in symbolic solutions, Julia has the large, modern and comprehensive numerical solver package.